# How to specific EventSetter.Handler to method of other class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this code

```
<EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

that the method I wrote in Handler have to be method of the class of that Window xaml
how to specific to other class method?

Comment: Need more information. Where is this XAML currently located? not in Window.xaml?

Comment: it's in Window.xaml.. but I have to use this method in every textbox.. so I have to wrote same method in every Window.xaml
that's why I ask if we can use method from class that just wrote once.. not in every window.xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To acheive what you are trying, you can create a common base class and have your event handler defined in that class.

**Base Class from my Sample:**

```
public class MyWindowBase : Window
{
    protected void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your handling code goes here.. 
    }
}
```

And then, make *all* your `Window`s derive from this new base class:

**MainWindow.xaml from my Sample:**

```
<wpfApplication5:MyWindowBase x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:wpfApplication5="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="TextBox1" />
    </Grid>
</wpfApplication5:MyWindowBase>
```

You will also have to update base class in the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MyWindowBase
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This way, all your windows can make use of one single handler defined in the base class. The only downside is you have to repeat the `EventSetter` code in all XAML files (of course, whereever you want to use that single handler).

**OPTION 2**

The other Option would be to move the `EventSetter` XAML to a `ResourceDictionary`, and have a code-behind for the ResourceDictionary and have the EventHandler there.

**ResourceDictionary XAML**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="WpfApplication5.Dictionary1">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**and Codebehind:**

```
public partial class Dictionary1 : ResourceDictionary
{
    public Dictionary1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
    }
}
```

And, then your window XAML, will become something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="TextBox1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps, or gives you some ideas on how to approach your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `EventSetter`, you can only use a handler in the code behind of the XAML file where it is declared. If you tried to reference a method from another class using an XML Namespace Prefix, then you would get an error from the compiler:

> Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid.

The only way that I can think of doing this is if your code behind has a reference to the class with the desired handler. In this case, you could do this:

In the handling class:

```
public void HandleMouseButtonEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // handle event here
}
```

In the code behind:

```
public void MouseButtonEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    handlingClass.HandleMouseButtonEvent(sender, e);
}
```