# How to use same method in more xaml files in TextBox (TextChanged="OnTextChanged")

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I have more xaml files. In each file I have:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>
```

In one code behind I have:

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myInput = sender as TextBox;

        myInput.Text = myInput.Text.Replace(",", ".").Trim();
        myInput.CaretIndex = myInput.Text.Length;
    }
```

How to use the `OnTexChanged` method in other xaml files (without copy/paste)?
Thanks.

Comment: You can add code behind to a resource dictionary (Google it ) and apply a handler in there via a style. Alternatively, you can use an attached event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/attached-events-overview?view=netdesktop-7.0

Comment: Can you tell how to do it to my TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution for me:

`ResourceDictionary.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="MyName.ResourceDictionary"
    x:ClassModifier="public">
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewTextInput" Handler="NumberValidationTextBox"/>
    <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="OnTextChanged"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Code behind:

```
public void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^-?[0-9]*[\\.,]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$");
    var futureText = $"{(sender as TextBox).Text}{e.Text}";
    e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(futureText);

}
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myInput = sender as TextBox;
    myInput.Text = myInput.Text.Replace(",", ".").Trim();
    myInput.CaretIndex = myInput.Text.Length;
}
```

In all .xaml files where want to use the TextBox'es:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StyleTemplate.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

lot of solutions to do that,
one is the creation of class wich derived form TextBox

1. create a wpf NET project (here called WpfApp3)
2. add class (here called ValidatedTextBox)

**ValidatedTextBox.cs**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public class ValidatedTextBox : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInitialized(e);
            //default values, just for test
            HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
            Padding = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
        }
        protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {           
            base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
            Regex regex = new Regex("^-?[0-9]*[\\.,]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$");
            var futureText = $"{Text}{e.Text}";
            e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(futureText);
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            Text = Text.Replace(",", ".").Trim();
            CaretIndex = Text.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

---

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow" x:Name="Root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:ValidatedTextBox Grid.Column="0"  Background="AliceBlue" Width="100" Height="50" Text="{Binding Val1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <local:ValidatedTextBox Grid.Column="1"  Background="AliceBlue" Width="100" Height="50" Text="{Binding Val2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Content="GetData" Height="59" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private string val1;
        public string Val1
        {
            get { return val1; }
            set 
            { 
                val1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Val1");
            }
        }
        private string val2;
        public string Val2
        {
            get { return val2; }
            set
            {
                val2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Val2");
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Val1 = "2";
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"value: {Val1}");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"value: {Val2}");
        }
        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void ValidatedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any shorter/easier way, like: `<TextBox TextChanged="MyOtherClassName.OnTextChanged"/>`?

Comment: i have give up FindVisual method and add binding for UserControl to trap he value of the TextBox..you have just to bind the value of the usercontrol to get the TextBox Content.  You have just one time the code of usercontrol. Its the utility of UserControl.dont Forget you have to trap the different values i suppose...

Comment: you could use te same event defined in one place, but the event will be for all TextBox see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216392/how-to-specific-eventsetter-handler-to-method-of-other-class

Comment: I have found a simple solution by using a class which derives from TextBox, i have changed the sample

Answer (score 1):

The event handler itself must be located in the same class so you cannot write something like `<TextBox TextChanged="MyOtherClassName.OnTextChanged"/>`.

But to encapsulate the actual functionality you could create a custom (but very simple) `TextBox` class:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        Text = Text.Replace(",", ".").Trim();
        CaretIndex = Text.Length;
    }
}
```

To reuse the functionality you then simply use your custom control instead of the built-in `TextBox` control, i.e. you replace `<TextBox TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>` by `<local:CustomTextBox>` in your XAML markup.

Comment: How to get value from the different textboxes?